# Missing deposit?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I'm having this bizarre problem. I've got this address A where I received two deposits, both are confirmed. I consolidated all my balance in a single address B (i.e. I sent my full balance to B). Since I moved my full balance I would expect all my addresses to be zero (except for B), but I noticed that address A has now non-zero balance: only one of the two deposits was used (let's call this output X). My guess is that the balance I'm getting with **getinfo** and **getbalance** is not actually my full balance and it's missing output X. Do you have any idea what may be happening? Things I've tried:

1. X appears unspent in block explorer
2. I ran **gettxout** with X and it correctly returns information (meaning X is actually not spent)
3. I ran **listunspent** and I'm not getting X (meaning it's spent?)

Thanks in advice!

Comment: What does the transaction you moved it with look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's a standard transaction.

Comment: The blockchain is transactions, that's it. If there is a problem it will be in the transaction. If you locate your transaction on the block chain you can see if X was involved at all. Also, did you try `listunspent X include_unsafe`, to see if locally you have X in an unconfirmed transaction maybe?

Comment: X was not part of the consolidation.  This led me to think that X was not being counted as part of my balance. I confirmed this by creating a raw transaction that transfers X to consolidation address B, and then my balance magically increased by the amount in X.

Comment: Your balance where? This is very confusing, it's not at all clear what you had before or what you have now or what you did or indeed what your problem is.

Comment: "I confirmed this by creating a raw transaction that transfers X" probably why it doesn't show up as unspent then.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm trying things on the fly. Basically the problem was that I had some deposits (tx outputs) that apparently were not being counted as part of my wallet balance. When I consolidated all my balance, those deposits (tx outputs) were not included in the consolidating tx (even when they were fully confirmed and other outputs in the same address were used in the consolidating tx). My previous comment stated that I tried manually sending (spending) those outputs into my consolidated address, and it worked, and my balance increased, which is very weird.

Comment: "(even when they were fully confirmed and other outputs in the same address were used in the consolidating tx)" You left them out of the transaction, simple as that. How? I don't know. Would need to see the commands you ran, or more detail about how you went about consoldation.

Comment: My wallet was fully sync'ed, I took note of the wallet balance (by means of getbalance) and I sent that amount to a new address (minus fees). That's the way I generated the consolidating tx. For some reason some outputs were not included in that tx and they were not even considered as part of the balance. It's worth mentioning that after consolidation the wallet balance remained the same (minus the consolidating tx fee).

Comment: So the first problem was your getbalance was less than expected (they were not even considered as part of the balance) but you carried on and sent anyway?

Comment: Actually I didn't know the wallet balance was incorrect. I only realized that later when I noticed there were unspent outputs. I usually trust getbalance when the wallet is fully sync'ed and all deposits are confirmed.